# vb.net Combobox Item Must be Saved on Formload

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub frmemployedetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        opendb()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT department from employedetails"

        'Execte reader function is used to hold more than one value from the table
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        ' Fill a combo box with the datareader
        Do While dr.Read = True
            cbodepartment = dr.Item(0)
        Loop

        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
    btnupdate.Enabled = False
    fill_grid()
    cbogender.Items.Add("Male")
    cbogender.Items.Add("Female")
End Sub
```

this is my Code  i m new into VB.net plz help me 
so that i can add Item into Combobox previously Entered
while Form Load it will Show up all the Distinct Items i Entered

Comment: Are you getting any errors. If so what are they.?

Comment: Bro Let me tell you, all i want to populate my datafield  in combobox from my database records how can i do that ?

Comment: Two things you are trying to add your dr.Item directly to your cbodepartment object not to its items collection. And if you are running in 64 bit windows any errors in the Form Load event will be swallowed and not shown. So try cboDepartment.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))

Comment: Yes i have 64 bit Version of Windows 7.

Comment: whenever i  run my project on formload i must be able to c previously added Records through Combobox so that i can choose them Directly instead of Typing again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate your `ComboBox` with the list of Departments contained into `employeedetails` database table you can try this:

```
Dim Connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("YourConnectionString")

        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT department FROM employedetails"

        Try
            Connection.Open()

            Dim DA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)
            Dim DS As New DataSet("DS")
            DA.Fill(DS)

            Dim DT As DataTable
            DT = DS.Tables(0)

            For Each DR As DataRow In DT.Rows    
                cbodepartment.Items.Add(DR.Item("department").ToString)
            Next

            Connection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Connection.Close()

        End Try
```

Comment: Im Getting only one record in combobox i want all Records with Distinct

Comment: It makes no sense. The SELECT statement retrieves all distinct departments from your table. Are you sure you have more than one department in your employeedetails table?

Comment: Yah Bro, it shows me only one record that is "IT" which is not available in my employedetails table i have more than 10 entries with 5 Different Departments

Comment: whenever i run my project on formload i must be able to c previously added Records through Combobox so that i can choose them Directly instead of Typing again

Comment: I'm very stumped about the process on how your combobox is populated with data that doesn't exist in your table. Try to execute that SQL statement directly in your db. What are the results?